# PVR texturetool build phase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, pvrtc

I'm currently completing an [iphone 3d programming book](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/)

The book says to add following python code into a build phase in xcode, to run the provided texturetool.

Book Quote

> a. Leave the shell as /bin/sh.
>
> b. Enter this directly into the script box:
>
> ```
> BIN=${PLATFORM_DIR}/../iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin  
> INFILE=${SRCROOT}/Textures/Grid16.png 
> OUTFILE=${SRCROOT}/Textures/Grid16.pvr 
> ${BIN}/texturetool -m -f PVR -e PVRTC $INFILE -o $OUTFILE
> ```
>
> c. Add this to Input Files:
>
> ```
> $(SRCROOT)/Textures/Grid16.png
> ```
>
> Add this to Output Files:
>
> ```
> $(SRCROOT)/Textures/Grid16.pvr
> ```

However when doing this I receive the following message.

```
Failed to load image
Failed to perform Encode
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Could anyone shed a light on this?

Comment: Issue was caused due to spaces in directories.

Comment: I've changed spaces to '\ ' and it failed while I typed it in Terminal and it works. I don't know why it still fails only in xCode.  Does anyone got any idea?

Comment: That's not Python code. It is some Bash.

Comment: `echo` is your friend. `echo $INFILE` will output in the filename into the build console. Does the path exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces in your directories!

Answer (score 0):

Replace $(SRCROOT) with ${SRCROOT}