# Texturetool convert flipped pvr file in Unity3d

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, pvrtc

I just convert png file to pvr file by [texturetool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html) .
But that imported pvr file was vertically flipped in Unity3D.
So, I can't replace it to the original sprite atlas(png file).

Here is the command that I was use to convert png file to pvr file

```
texturetool -m -f PVR -e PVRTC image.png -o image.pvr
```

Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Thank you

Ref: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671680/pvr-texturetool-build-phase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are doing this on runtime change Y tiling of your material. if you are doing it in the editor (just once) than you can use [Pixlr.com](https://pixlr.com/editor/) for quick fix.

Comment: Thank you for answer. For the current situation, I also flip png file before convert to pvr(Same as your answer). But, I want a solution how to fix it in Unity3D.

Comment: ok i wrote a little script for you. make a folder named Editor in your Assets folder and put this script in it. A menu item will appear in the menu bar on top called "Image Manipulation". select your texture in the project window then click "Image Manipulation" >> "Flip Vertical". here is the script: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwTTUlmZWV7penlYT1k4MmJ0aVk

Comment: p.s. forgot to tell you, you need to have read/write enabled on your texture - select it and in the inspector change the Texture Type to Advanced, then check the Read/Write Enabled checkbox, apply